# Differential equation/limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

how can I show, that each solution $x(t), t\geq 0$ of $$x'=x^2-x^6$$
with $x(0)>0 $ $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} x(t)=1$ holds.

I can calculate the solution, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation has three obvious constant solutions, $x=-1,x=0,x=1$, and no solution can cross these loci.

If $0<x<1$, $x'>0$ so that the solution is strictly increasing, towards $1$. If $1<x$, the solution is strictly decreasing, towards $1$.

Note that the convergence cannot stop "before" $1$, as this would correspond to another root of $x^2-x^6$.

---

Note that the equation is autonomous (no explicit $t$), so that all solutions are horizontal translates of each other.

---

We can make a more quantitative statement by setting $z:=1+x$, so that

$$z'=-4z+o(z)$$

and an asymptotic solution is

$$z=ce^{-4t},$$ or $$x=1+ce^{-4t}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much:) You made everything clear:)

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the vector field. In
$$
x'=x^2(1+x^2)(1-x^2)
$$
you find that there are constant solutions at $x=-1,0,1$ that no other solution can cross, that solutions in $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ are growing and in $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$ are falling. For $x_0>0$ they thus converge towards $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)